how to specify conditional rustflags in cargo config file
I need to add
"-C link-arg /STACK:4000000"
but only for windows builds. I could not follow the cargo book and could not find any sample config.toml files.

You can define some target-specific properties via [target.<TARGET>] sections. The Cargo configuration documentation shows what fields are possible there:

[target.<triple>]
linker = "…"              # linker to use
runner = "…"              # wrapper to run executables
rustflags = ["…", "…"]    # custom flags for `rustc`
rustdocflags = ["…", "…"] # custom flags for `rustdoc`


So you would want something like this in your ./.cargo/config.toml:
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg", "/STACK:4000000"]


for those coming here for the precise answer its ["-C", "link-arg=/STACK:4000000"] (my bad in the question)
